# Why is the data in the serializer not shown in django?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm going to make four serializers and put three serializers in one serializer. However, only one of the three serializers operates normally and the other two do not. I made the structure of the three serializer almost identical, but I don't understand if only one works. Please help me solve the problem.

JSON

```
    {
        "pk": 1,
        "author": {
            "username": "username",
            "email": "email",
            "profile": "image_link"
        }, # AuthorSerializer is worked
        "title": "title1",
        "text": "text1",
        "view": 0,
        # ImageSerializer is not worked
        "like_count": 0,
        # LikerSerializer is not worked
        "comment_count": 0,
        "tag": "hash tag",
        "created_at": "time"
    }
```

serializers.py

```
class AuthorSerializer (serializers.ModelSerializer) :
    profile = serializers.ImageField(use_url=True)

    class Meta :
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'profile')

class ImageSerializer (serializers.ModelSerializer) :
    image = serializers.ImageField(use_url=True)

    class Meta :
        model = Image
        fields = ('image', )

class LikerSerializer (serializers.ModelSerializer) :
    id = serializers.IntegerField(source='liker.pk')

    class Meta :
        model = Like
        fields = ('id', )

class PostSerializer (serializers.ModelSerializer) :
    author = AuthorSerializer(read_only=True)
    image = ImageSerializer(read_only=True, many=True)
    like_count = serializers.ReadOnlyField()
    liker = LikerSerializer(read_only=True, many=True)
    comment_count = serializers.ReadOnlyField()

    class Meta :
        model = Post
        fields = ('pk', 'author', 'title', 'text', 'image', 'view', 'like_count', 'liker',  'comment_count', 'tag', 'created_at')
 
    def create (self, validated_data) :
        images_data = self.context['request'].FILES
        post = Post.objects.create(**validated_data)

        for image_data in images_data.getlist('image') :
            Image.objects.create(post=post, image=image_data)

        return post

    def validate (self, attrs) :
        title = attrs.get('title', '')
        text = attrs.get('text', '')

        error = {}

        if title is None and text is None :
            error['message'] = '제목과 본문은 빈칸일 수 없습니다.'
            serializers.ValidationError(error)

        if title is None :
            error['message'] = '제목은 빈칸일 수 없습니다.'
            serializer.ValidationError(error)

        if text is None :
            error['message'] = '본문은 빈칸일 수 없습니다.'    
            serializer.ValidationError(error)

        return attrs
```

models.py

```
class Post (models.Model) :
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='author', null=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=40, null=True)
    text = models.TextField(max_length=300, null=True)
    tag = models.CharField(max_length=511, null=True)
    view = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__ (self) :
        return self.title

    @property
    def comment_count (self) :
        return Comment.objects.filter(post=self.pk).count()

    @property
    def like_count (self) :
        return Like.objects.filter(post=self.pk).count()
 
class Image (models.Model) :
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)

class Comment (models.Model) :
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text = models.TextField(max_length=200)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class Like (models.Model) :
    liker = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

Comment: Image and Liker are ```one to many``` related?

Comment: Can you show your models?

Comment: If you make your helper serializers as `read_only` they will not be validated by `PostSerializer` while sending Post Request. Remove `read_only` parameters from helper serializers.

Comment: @Charnel I add it !

Comment: @adnankaya If I remove read_only, It makes error "Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `image` on serializer `PostSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `Post` instance."

Comment: @dorintufar yes It's one to many

Comment: @leedjango change as  `ImageSerializer(required=False, many=True)` and others.

Comment: @adnankaya It's not worked for me ..